# In documentdb can i join across collections and update partition key for document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I just added a partition key while creating collection which is `"/countryId"`.

1. is it possible to update countryId for document ?
2. can i join across collections in documentdb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to update countryId for document ?

No. Once an attribute as assigned as `Partition Key` for a collection, it can't be changed. Furthermore, you can't change the value of a `Partition Key` in an existing document. You must delete and reinsert the document with new partition key value. <del>You should be able to change the value though (say changing countryId value from 1 to 2 of a document).</del>

> Can i join across collections in documentdb ?

No again. Querying across collection is not supported. What you would need to do is issue queries against each collection separately and then the work with the data on the client side.

Comment: One edit suggestion - the partition key of a document cannot be modified. You have to delete and reinsert with the new partition key value.

Comment: Thank you @AravindRamachandran. I have updated my answer.